# PHP Reading the content between tags

Tags: php, javascript

If there are multiple hyperlinks in a webpage, How do I recognize them using JavaScript? Also, how do I store the content of the hyperlink in a variable, so that the data stored in the variable will be used the query a database and populate results in another webpage?

For example there are many links in the webpage like this

```
<a href="update.php">text 1</a>.
<a href="update.php">text 2</a>

<a href="update.php">text N</a>
```

User can click any one of the hyperlinks in the webpage. If user clicks on hyperlink 'text4', `text4` should be saved in a variable. Then pass the variable value to update.php, where database is queried using the statement `SELECT text4 from table sometable` and results are populated.

Answer (score 6):

Easiest way is to write the hrefs like this:

```
  <a id="text1" href="update.php?q=text1">text 1</a>
  <a id="text2" href="update.php?q=text2">text 2</a>
    .
    .
  <a id="textN" href="update.php?q=textN">text N</a>
```

Then read `$_GET['q']` in php (or the equivalent in other server-side languages) and build your SQL accordingly.

To recognize the hyperlink using javascript you can use multiple methods. I will recommend using `document.getElementById`. For eg if you identify the hyperlinks with id's text1,text2....textN, then you can recognize them in javascript using:

```
 var text1 = document.getElementById('text1');
 var text2 = document.getElementById('text2');
  .
  .
 var textN = document.getElementById('textN');
```

and then you can handle these text1,text3.....textN Accordingly

Comment: This is definitely the easiest way, but the OP also asked about using Javascript.

Comment: @Herbert A prime example of the XY problem.

Comment: @Juhana: The OP asked two questions: "How do I recognize them using JavaScript? _Also_, how do I store the content of the hyperlink in a variable...". This answers the second question, but not the first. I don't see how this is related to the XY problem at all.

Comment: @Herbert I think it's quite clear that he wanted to recognize the links using JS because he wanted to solve the problem of sending data to the server. YMMV.

Comment: @Juhana: Not necessarily. He may have wanted to "ajaxify" it as well.

Comment: @Herbert ok I am answering that too.

Comment: @Juhana ok I am answering that too.

Answer (score 2):

You could use jQuery, as well:

```
<div id="myLinks">

    <a href="update.php">text 1</a>.
    <a href="update.php">text 2</a>

    <a href="update.php">text N</a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$("#myLinks a").click(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();
    var currentLink = $(this).text();

    alert(currentLink);

});
```